# Choosing second page in domain with same path for local overrides

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-devtools

I wish to use Chrome devtools' "local overrides" for a test project. I wish to only change a single character on this page, and save it to my computer. On the webpage I have chosen, there is a page I wish to change. This page is only accessible via clicking a button on the previous page. Both the previous page and the page I wish to change have the exact same URL, like so:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask?guided=false (page 1 with button)
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask?guided=false (page 2 reached from page 1)

The pages hold some similar elements that do not change, but a large portion of the page switches from one table to another.

All elements in the table are text with hyperlinks, and in regular inspect element it is trivial to find and replace the character on the second page, but within local overrides' 'Network,' and 'Page' tabs, II can only ever find reference and elements of the first page. Is what I am attempting even possible? Please excuse any ignorance on my part, I am simply trying to better understand local overrides, and how it would work here.

Comment: You can do it all in one page and use JQuery to change the "page look" based off what is clicked

Comment: @AdamBuchananSmith Could you please expand on this? What I want is that every time I go back to this page, and get to that secondary page on this computer, I want to see that changed element. How would one accomplish this with JQuery? Also, thank you for your reply!